# Problem with define the structure (circle)

Tags: c, structure

So here is the problem:
Define the circle structure with field the radius and the square structure with field the length. Create a function that accepts as parameters a void * type indicator and an integer parameter. If its value is 0, the pointer indicates a circle type structure, otherwise it indicates a square type structure. The function increases the value of the field of the structure shown by the pointer by 5 and returns the pointer. Write a program that controls the operation of the function.

And here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct circle{
    float radius;

};

struct square{
    float side;
    float len;
};

void* resize(void *shape, int type);
int main(void){
    circle *p1, c = {2.45};
    square *p2, s ={4};
    p1 = (circle*)resize(&c, 0); //Error in circle
    p2 = (square*)resize(&s, 1); //Error in square
    printf("%f %d\n", p1->radius, p2 ->len);
    return 0;
}

void* resize(void *shape, int type)
{
    if(type ==0)
        ((circle*)shape)->radius +=5;//Error in circle
    else
        ((square*)shape)->len +=5; //Error in square
    return shape;
}
enter code here
```

And i have errors.
Someone knows how to solve this?
Error is:

```
E:\TDM-GCC\bin\untitled5\main.c: In function 'main':
E:\TDM-GCC\bin\untitled5\main.c:14:5: error: unknown type name 'circle'; use 'struct' keyword to refer to the type
     circle *p1, c = {2.45};
     ^~~~~~
     struct 
E:\TDM-GCC\bin\untitled5\main.c:15:5: error: unknown type name 'square'; use 'struct' keyword to refer to the type
     square *p2, s ={4};
     ^~~~~~
     struct 
E:\TDM-GCC\bin\untitled5\main.c:16:11: error: 'circle' undeclared (first use in this function)
     p1 = (circle*)resize(&c, 0);
           ^~~~~~
E:\TDM-GCC\bin\untitled5\main.c:16:11: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
E:\TDM-GCC\bin\untitled5\main.c:16:18: error: expected expression before ')' token
     p1 = (circle*)resize(&c, 0);
                  ^
E:\TDM-GCC\bin\untitled5\main.c:17:11: error: 'square' undeclared (first use in this function)
     p2 = (square*)resize(&s, 1);
           ^~~~~~
E:\TDM-GCC\bin\untitled5\main.c:17:18: error: expected expression before ')' token
     p2 = (square*)resize(&s, 1);
                  ^
E:\TDM-GCC\bin\untitled5\main.c:18:25: error: request for member 'radius' in something not a structure or union
     printf("%f %d\n", p1->radius, p2 ->len);
                         ^~
E:\TDM-GCC\bin\untitled5\main.c:18:38: error: request for member 'len' in something not a structure or union
     printf("%f %d\n", p1->radius, p2 ->len);
                                      ^~
E:\TDM-GCC\bin\untitled5\main.c: In function 'resize':
E:\TDM-GCC\bin\untitled5\main.c:25:11: error: 'circle' undeclared (first use in this function)
         ((circle*)shape)->radius +=5;
           ^~~~~~
E:\TDM-GCC\bin\untitled5\main.c:25:18: error: expected expression before ')' token
         ((circle*)shape)->radius +=5;
                  ^
E:\TDM-GCC\bin\untitled5\main.c:27:11: error: 'square' undeclared (first use in this function)
         ((square*)shape)->len +=5;
           ^~~~~~
E:\TDM-GCC\bin\untitled5\main.c:27:18: error: expected expression before ')' token
         ((square*)shape)->len +=5;
                  ^
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\untitled5.dir\build.make:62: CMakeFiles/untitled5.dir/main.c.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:75: CMakeFiles/untitled5.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/untitled5.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: untitled5] Error 2
```

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: If you get build errors then please [edit] your question to include a full and complete copy-paste (as text) of the build output. Also please add comments on the lines in the code where you get the errors. Also please take some time to read (or refresh) [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `circle *p1` -> `struct circle *p1`. Same for `square`. That is, the type is `struct circle` not `circle`.

Comment: You might want to take a couple of steps back, find your beginners book about C (or buy one or two), and start over on the chapters about structures.

Comment: Still not working!

Comment: In short: `circle` is not a type. `struct circle` is a type.

Comment: Are you really saying you made that change and there were still exactly the same errors? I doubt it. So common sense would tell you that "stiil not working" is not a sensible reply if you are seeking further help. How about being a bit more specific? Same errors? Different errors?

Comment: Compiler with that change dont find some errors. The output of the program is:7.450000 0 but is not that i want.

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: Learning how to use a debugger would be very useful once you've fixed the build errors. With a debugger you can step through the code, statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values. You could for example step into the `resize` function to see what it really does, and what values it really does change (and to what).

Answer (score 0):

you can't use 'circle' and you other struct as is.

You need to use 'struct circle' etc.

If you don't want to use 'struct circle' you can do:

```
typedef struct circle{
    float radius;
} Circle;
```

and just use 'Circle'